# How to configure Istio envoy proxy as Outbound decorator

Tags: kubernetes, istio, envoyproxy

The idea to:

- set up additional port (8101) for Istio envoy proxy and use it inside of pod
  (thus it is not necessary to set up additional Gateway and VirtualService for it, port only for inner uses)
- apply EnvoyFilter on the port, EnvoyFilter by using Lua scripts will doing decorating of reguests

[image]

Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: Could you explain more precisely what you want to do? Add a header to every request?

Comment: @jt97 Hi, I added schema, I am looking how to implement decoration part on the schema

Comment: @jt97  "Add a header to every request?"- it can be any header .. more important how to set up additional port for inner call